# Aligning a long table to the left in latex

Tags: longtable

I know that there are questions like this. However, I can not solve my problem!
I can not align my table to the left. In this was the title of my table is aligned to the left and the table is centered. In addition, I would like to add a note at the bottom of my table

I have this long table

```
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{\label{Income_level_tabel}Countries by income level.}\\
\toprule
Countries            &  Income  \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{\label{Income_level_tabel}Countries by income level. - continued form previous page}\\

\toprule
Countries            &    Income  \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
Albania              & Upper-middle income         \\
Algeria              & Upper-middle income            \\
Argentina            & Upper-middle income          \\
Armenia              & Lower-middle income            \\
Austria              & High income                \\ \addlinespace
Bangladesh           & Lower-middle income                 \\
Belarus              & Upper-middle income                 \\
Belgium              & High income                \\
Benin                & Low income                 \\
Bulgaria             & Upper-middle income            \\ \addlinespace
Burkina Faso         & Low income                \\
Burundi              & Low income                \\
Cambodia             &  Lower-middle income                \\
Cameroon             & Lower-middle income          \\
Chile                &  High income            \\ \addlinespace
China                & Upper-middle income                \\
Colombia             & Upper-middle income                \\
Croatia              & Upper-middle income                \\      
Czech Republic       & High income                  \\
Denmark              & High income                 \\ \addlinespace
Egypt, Arab Rep.     & Lower-middle income          \\
El Salvador          & Lower-middle income                 \\
Estonia              & High income                  \\
Ethiopia             & Low income                 \\
Finland              & High income                  \\ \addlinespace
France               & High income                  \\
Greece               & High income             \\
Guinea               & Low income             \\
Honduras             & Lower-middle income          \\
Hungary              & High income               \\ \addlinespace
India                & Lower-middle income                \\
Indonesia            & Lower-middle income           \\
Ireland              & High income                   \\
Israel               & High income                   \\ 
Italy                & High income                    \\ \addlinespace
Jordan               & Lower-middle income            \\
Korea, Rep.          & High income                 \\
Kyrgyz Republic      & Lower-middle income                 \\
Lao PDR              & Lower-middle income                 \\
Latvia               & High income                   \\ \addlinespace
Lesotho              & Lower-middle income                 \\
Lithuania            & High income                 \\
Madagascar           & Low income             \\
Malawi               & Low income           \\
Malaysia             & Upper-middle income                 \\ \addlinespace
Mali                 & Low income                  \\
Mauritania           & Lower-middle income               \\
Mexico               & Upper-middle income            \\
Moldova              & Lower-middle income           \\
Mongolia             & Lower-middle income               \\ \addlinespace
Morocco              & Lower-middle income            \\
Mozambique           & Low income            \\
Nepal                & Low income                  \\
Netherlands          & High income               \\
North Macedonia      & Upper-middle income                \\ \addlinespace
Norway               & High income                \\
Panama               & Upper-middle income              \\
Peru                 & Upper-middle income            \\
Philippines          & Lower-middle income         \\
Poland               & High income            \\ \addlinespace
Portugal             & High income               \\
Romania              & Upper-middle income            \\
Russian Federation   & Upper-middle income            \\
Slovenia             &  High income                \\
Spain                &  High income                \\ \addlinespace
Sweden               &  High income                \\
Switzerland          & High income                \\
Syrian Arab Republic &  Lower-middle income                 \\ 
Tajikistan           &  Lower-middle income                 \\
Tanzania             & Low income              \\ \addlinespace
Thailand             & Upper-middle income                \\
Togo                 & Low income              \\
Tunisia              & Lower-middle income                 \\ 
Uganda               & Low income              \\
Ukraine              & Lower-middle income \\ \addlinespace
United Kingdom       & High income                 \\
United States        & High income                \\
Uruguay              & High income        \\
Uzbekistan           & Lower-middle income             \\
Vietnam              & Lower-middle income            \\  

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but probably you could remove the word "income"  from every row as it is already specified in the column header. With this modification you could probably fit both halfs of the table onto a single page.

Comment: @leandriis thank you !

Answer (score 1):

A `longtable` is horizontally centered by default. In order to left align a `longtable`, use its optional argument as follows:

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{ll}
```

Full and compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{ll}
\caption{\label{Income_level_tabel}Countries by income level.}\\
\toprule
Countries            &  Income  \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{\label{Income_level_tabel}Countries by income level. - continued form previous page}\\

\toprule
Countries            &    Income  \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
Albania              & Upper-middle income  \\
Algeria              & Upper-middle income  \\
Argentina            & Upper-middle income  \\
Armenia              & Lower-middle income  \\
Austria              & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Bangladesh           & Lower-middle income  \\
Belarus              & Upper-middle income  \\
Belgium              & High income          \\
Benin                & Low income           \\
Bulgaria             & Upper-middle income  \\ 
\addlinespace
Burkina Faso         & Low income           \\
Burundi              & Low income           \\
Cambodia             & Lower-middle income  \\
Cameroon             & Lower-middle income  \\
Chile                & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
China                & Upper-middle income  \\
Colombia             & Upper-middle income  \\
Croatia              & Upper-middle income  \\      
Czech Republic       & High income          \\
Denmark              & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Egypt, Arab Rep.     & Lower-middle income  \\
El Salvador          & Lower-middle income  \\
Estonia              & High income          \\
Ethiopia             & Low income           \\
Finland              & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
France               & High income          \\
Greece               & High income          \\
Guinea               & Low income           \\
Honduras             & Lower-middle income  \\
Hungary              & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
India                & Lower-middle income  \\
Indonesia            & Lower-middle income  \\
Ireland              & High income          \\
Israel               & High income          \\ 
Italy                & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Jordan               & Lower-middle income  \\
Korea, Rep.          & High income          \\
Kyrgyz Republic      & Lower-middle income  \\
Lao PDR              & Lower-middle income  \\
Latvia               & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Lesotho              & Lower-middle income  \\
Lithuania            & High income          \\
Madagascar           & Low income           \\
Malawi               & Low income           \\
Malaysia             & Upper-middle income  \\ 
\addlinespace
Mali                 & Low income           \\
Mauritania           & Lower-middle income  \\
Mexico               & Upper-middle income  \\
Moldova              & Lower-middle income  \\
Mongolia             & Lower-middle income  \\ 
\addlinespace
Morocco              & Lower-middle income  \\
Mozambique           & Low income           \\
Nepal                & Low income           \\
Netherlands          & High income          \\
North Macedonia      & Upper-middle income  \\ 
\addlinespace
Norway               & High income          \\
Panama               & Upper-middle income  \\
Peru                 & Upper-middle income  \\
Philippines          & Lower-middle income  \\
Poland               & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Portugal             & High income          \\
Romania              & Upper-middle income  \\
Russian Federation   & Upper-middle income  \\
Slovenia             & High income          \\
Spain                & High income          \\ 
\addlinespace
Sweden               & High income          \\
Switzerland          & High income          \\
Syrian Arab Republic & Lower-middle income  \\ 
Tajikistan           & Lower-middle income  \\
Tanzania             & Low income           \\ 
\addlinespace
Thailand             & Upper-middle income  \\
Togo                 & Low income           \\
Tunisia              & Lower-middle income  \\ 
Uganda               & Low income           \\
Ukraine              & Lower-middle income  \\ 
\addlinespace
United Kingdom       & High income          \\
United States        & High income          \\
Uruguay              & High income          \\
Uzbekistan           & Lower-middle income  \\
Vietnam              & Lower-middle income  \\  

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

---

As an alternative, I suggest the following layout with which you are able to fith the whole table onto a single page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{3.75pt}
\caption{\label{Income_level_tabel}Countries by income level.}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Countries            &  Income         && Countries            &  Income      \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
Albania              & Upper-middle    && Lesotho              & Lower-middle \\
Algeria              & Upper-middle    && Lithuania            & High         \\
Argentina            & Upper-middle    && Madagascar           & Low          \\
Armenia              & Lower-middle    && Malawi               & Low          \\
Austria              & High            && Malaysia             & Upper-middle \\ 
\addlinespace
Bangladesh           & Lower-middle    && Mali                 & Low          \\
Belarus              & Upper-middle    && Mauritania           & Lower-middle \\
Belgium              & High            && Mexico               & Upper-middle \\
Benin                & Low             && Moldova              & Lower-middle \\
Bulgaria             & Upper-middle    && Mongolia             & Lower-middle \\ 
\addlinespace
Burkina Faso         & Low             && Morocco              & Lower-middle \\
Burundi              & Low             && Mozambique           & Low          \\
Cambodia             & Lower-middle    && Nepal                & Low          \\
Cameroon             & Lower-middle    && Netherlands          & High         \\
Chile                & High            && North Macedonia      & Upper-middle \\
 \addlinespace
China                & Upper-middle    && Norway               & High         \\
Colombia             & Upper-middle    && Panama               & Upper-middle \\
Croatia              & Upper-middle    && Peru                 & Upper-middle \\      
Czech Republic       & High            && Philippines          & Lower-middle \\
Denmark              & High            && Poland               & High         \\ 
\addlinespace
Egypt, Arab Rep.     & Lower-middle    && Portugal             & High         \\
El Salvador          & Lower-middle    && Romania              & Upper-middle \\
Estonia              & High            && Russian Federation   & Upper-middle \\
Ethiopia             & Low             && Slovenia             & High         \\
Finland              & High            && Spain                & High         \\ 
\addlinespace
France               & High            && Sweden               & High         \\
Greece               & High            && Switzerland          & High         \\
Guinea               & Low             && Syrian Arab Republic & Lower-middle \\
Honduras             & Lower-middle    && Tajikistan           & Lower-middle \\
Hungary              & High            && Tanzania             & Low          \\ 
\addlinespace
India                & Lower-middle    && Thailand             & Upper-middle \\
Indonesia            & Lower-middle    && Togo                 & Low          \\
Ireland              & High            && Tunisia              & Lower-middle \\
Israel               & High            && Uganda               & Low          \\ 
Italy                & High            && Ukraine              & Lower-middle \\ 
\addlinespace
Jordan               & Lower-middle    && United Kingdom       & High         \\
Korea, Rep.          & High            && United States        & High         \\
Kyrgyz Republic      & Lower-middle    && Uruguay              & High         \\
Lao PDR              & Lower-middle    && Uzbekistan           & Lower-middle \\
Latvia               & High            && Vietnam              & Lower-middle \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it says "invalid enviorment comand" @leandriis

Comment: @CarlotaOliveira, do you load `longtable` package in your document preamble?

Comment: @CarlotaOliveira: I have updated my anser to include a complete and compilable minimal example that shows hoe to use the optionalargument of the `longtable` environment. With this code, I can not reproduce the error message you get.